# Query by empty JsonField in django

Tags: python, django, django-jsonfield

I need to query a model by a `JsonField`, I want to get all records that have empty value ([]):

I used `MyModel.objects.filter(myjsonfield=[])` but it's not working, it returns 0 result though there's records having `myjsonfield=[]`

Answer (score 6):

Use the dunder `__exact` for this.  The `__isnull=True` does not work because the JSONField is technically not null.

**MyModel entries where `myjsonfield` is empty:**

`MyModel.objects.include(myjsonfield__exact=[])`

**MyModel entries where `myjsonfield` is *not* empty:**

`MyModel.objects.exclude(myjsonfield__exact=[])`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-exact

I believe if you've set the `default=dict` in your model then you should use `{}` (eg: `myjsonfield__exact={}`) instead of `[]` but I haven't tested this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Firstly, Django actually recommends that you declare JSONField with immutable/callable default values. For your example:

   ```
    class MyModel(models.Model):
        myjsonfield = models.JSONField(null=True, default=list)
   ```
2. Secondly, to query by `null` JSONField:

   ```
    MyModel.objects.filter(myjsonfield__isnull=True)
   ```

   To query for fields having `default` value (`[]` in your case):

   ```
    MyModel.objects.filter(myjsonfield__exact=[])
   ```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#querying-jsonfield for more details and examples.

Answer (score 0):

JSONfield should be `default={}` i.e., a dictionary, not a list.

Comment: No it shouldn't. JSON can be a list or a dict at root level. In Django having it as default={} doesn't return in order of entry. Having it as a list allows some order to it.

Comment: It can be either.  `default=dict` or `default=list` since JSON can be either a dict or a list.  Don't set it to actual value of {} or [] and don't actually call the function (eg. `dict()`) though.  Set it to the name of the function that produces the value.  It will be called when it needs to set a default.

Answer (score -1):

Try `MyModel.objects.filter(myjsonfield='[]')`.

Comment: same thing,  it returns 0 result